# Pig script - regex filter string which is not end with dash number

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I am trying to use regex to filter strings that do not end with `-<single digit number>`

For example:
match:

```
-1000
666er4-34234-999j
dkwo-67
```

mismatch:

```
asd-ertt-1234-2
111-2222-0
-7
```

Comment: I have match string with number as myStr = FILTER strs BY NOT(str matches '^.+?\\d$' ); any idea on how to deal with the "-"?

Comment: Neither of those strings ends with `-`.

Comment: Hi, i mean -number. Somehow the question ate my -<single digit number> @CAustin

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/B5uqWu/3

Comment: Just match `.*-\d$`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use anchors

```
^(?!.*-\d$).+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7OctTp/1/).